# Can someone explain Settings to me and how to use them in C#?

Tags: c#

Basically something I'm working on requires me to use Settings. I've never used Settings when it comes to C# and VS and the guides I've tried reading on the internet aren't really clearing it up for me. So I've got a few questions and if anyone could answer them then that would be brilliant.

1. What is a setting and what's it's purpose?
2. I've declared some settings, now how do I use them in my code?
3. Can I declare a setting as a variable or are they already variables that can be used?

An example is that I've got these codes in my Settings "BL,CC,CW,DX,DL,DU,F2,HA,JL,LD,PR,PS,S,SC,SF,UD,WL,ZC,ZD", they're called Codes

1. how can I use these Codes in the context of my code that when something is equal to one of these codes, do something else?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I've read that. Most of it made sense but It'd be nice to see it explained in a context that I've set to help me fully understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx)

What is a setting and what's it's purpose?

> The .NET Framework [..] allows you to **create and access values that are persisted between application execution sessions**. These values are called settings. Settings can represent **user preferences, or valuable information the application needs to use**. For example, you might create a series of settings that store user preferences for the color scheme of an application.

How do I use them in my code? Are they already variables that can be used?

> You can read both application-scope and user-scope settings at run time with the Properties namespace. The Properties namespace exposes all of the default settings for the project by using the Properties.Settings.Default object. When writing code that uses settings, **all settings appear in IntelliSense and are strongly typed**. Thus, if you have a setting that is of type System.Drawing.Color, for example, you can use it without having to cast it first, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> this.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.myColor;
> ```

As for your specific question, you might want to look into something like `string.Contains()`.